# In-app purchasing (IAP) plugin for PhoneGap 2.0 on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, in-app-purchase

The current IAP plugin for PhoneGap seems to only support up to 1.6.0: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/InAppPurchaseManager

Are there IAP plugins that support PhoneGap 2.0 on iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find :

https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/InAppPurchaseManager

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for your answer. Since links can go bad, try adding a description of how to reach the link in case this direct link stops working in the future.

Comment: I undestand John, but here, the answer is the link for the other version, I can not explain the differences in sources.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a better one, I created an updated version and Example Code.
https://github.com/usmart/InAppPurchaseManager-EXAMPLE